# Python urllib2 and urlopen with utf-8 signs

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, urllib2

how is it possible to pass a unicode string to the urllib2.urlopen(url) function?

I want to access a pdf-file with an utf-8 encoded url:

```
<a href="investments-%C2%A7-73g-legal.html">Link to pdf</a>
```

where the *%C2%A7 stands for the section sign: §*

If i pass this unicode url string to the urlopen method it throws an exception:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa7' in position 105: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If i ignore encoding errors: `url.encode("ascii",errors='ignore')` the link adress is not valid any more.

Can anybody give me a hint how to solve that problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: What exactly did you pass to `urlopen()`? Can you give us the output of `print(repr(url_you_used))` please?

Comment: u'177.23.125.41/2013-12-20-investments-\xa7-7g-legal-zwe.pdf'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something along these lines, in b, you will then find an utf8 string suitable for urllib2 (you have to complete it with a meaningful location, though...). Btw, printing the decoded **b** will show you the **§**

```
import urllib
import urllib2
a='investments-%C2%A7-73g-legal.html'
b=urllib.unquote(a)

print (b.decode('utf8'))

urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost/' + b)
```

Comment: Hi thx so far, i tried your solution but i'm still getting the exception 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa7' in position 105: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: at what statement do you get that error? Could you post code that throws the exception?